What are the retaining clips on the hinge side of a casement widow called?
I'm trying to make my own casement windows to match other windows in my house. I understand the crank mechanism, hinge mechanisms, locks, and lock keepers, but on the hinge side of my existing windows there are these clips that come in pairs and I can't seem to find any reference to them when looking for casement hardware online.
I had thought maybe these were to pull the windows tighter against the weather stripping, but on closer inspection I don't think they make much contact when the windows close. Now I'm wondering if they're there to hold the widow in the event of wind loading, so the non-locking side doesn't blow out.
Picture is of the hardware I've got. I can add more pictures if necessary, but this is the best angle I think. The window actuators say Jeld-Wen, but I have no idea how old they are. I would guess probably 30 years, as the previous owners told me they last remodeled in the 90s.

Here's a zoomed-out picture. My pointer finger is in the groove for the window screen, middle finger is on the weather stripping.


if they interlock when the window is closed, then they may be anti-bulgrary devices

try contacting Jeld-Wen

I think you're right on both counts--they ensure that the sash is snug against the seal, and they prevent movement due to wind or interior pressure bursts. They may not have a name. Seek out a parts diagram for a similar window from Jeld-Wen and call them if you need more detail.

I found them - they're called snubbers. From this site (no affiliation):

Snubbers prevent bowing of tall casement windows, or wide awning windows and have been found to be useful with double-hung windows in improving the seals of the bottom and top rails in the closed position.

